# Times Elapsed method seems missing in JMC 7 (in method profiling)

Tags: performance, profiling, jmc, jfr

I'm using JMC tool with JFR to do profiling on Java application.
After doing a record, and loading the JFR file, when i go to "Method Profiling", i saw Top package and top class and stack trace associated. In stack trace saw number of metod's call but i don't see time elapsed in a method.
Could you tell me what to do to see time elapsed for profiling method[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WHxe.png)

Answer (score 0):

The way JFR collects data is by sampling thread stacks, so there is no information in a recording on how long time a method has executed. The reason JFR uses sampling is to keep the overhead low and not skew the result by adding instrumentation to the application.

Comment: So then JMC + JFR is not good for CPU profiling?

Comment: JMC/JFR can show which methods that executes the most in your Java application, not the number of CPU ticks.